# Multiple windows in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a user interface class CarSimulation below for a vehicle game called "Cars". I want to be able to run a CarSimulation associated with an object of Cars, and a second, third etc CarSimulaion windows with each CarSimulation associated with a different object of Cars.

Could you give me some directions?

```
public class CarSimulation implements SimulationListener

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                CarSimulation window = new CarSimulation();
                window.CarSimulation.setVisible(true);
                Cars cargame = new Cars();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try JinternalFrame. Allows you to have many Open child windows at the Same Time

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JFrame for your main window. And then, use a JDialog for each instance of simulation you run.